# How can I customize the Advanced forum layout as shown in image?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

Image in red are current default provided by the advanced drupal forum and image in blue marks what I want. So layout shown for A, B, C, in the blue lined image, that I want. In short I want to customize the layout of the original Advanced theme layout to wherever I want to place. Is it possible.[image: Current Adaptive theme layout - red lined]

[image: I want to customize- blue lines layout]

Comment: yes, you just need to fiddle with the template files inside the advanced forum module skin folder and with the css.

Comment: Ok, I found the several .tpl.php files under the naked style, may be I have to dig in the codes and template files and needs to get output from by altering those codes, Thanks for input, appreciated.

Comment: no prob, I have modified/altered the forum before, so that's how I know.

Comment: Hey, could you suggest any link or source to learn coding in template.php and .tpl.php. May be you would have referred those during your time.

Comment: I don't really have one. I picked it up from here, and various other sources. Also, by fiddling around with the template files. All I can tell you is that template.php is used for overriding stuff using theme functions.

Comment: For this use case, you don't need template.php, just the tpl.php files of your forum skin/style. Also, there is a skin that already has the author pane like you want except it's on the left side instead of the right.

Comment: From your 1st picture. All you have to is print A after B. Then with css use `display: inline-block` on both A and B **OR** `float: left;` B only.

Comment: Yes, you are right, looks like I just need to deal with tpl.php as I just want to alter the position of the fields, and other theme related can be done with css.